# Ecto Changeset - association not casted, if no input is given

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a User schema

```
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    has_one :user_role, UserRole
  end

  def changeset(%User{} = user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :username])
    |> validate_required([:name, :username])
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end
```

and the UserRole schema

```
  schema "userroles" do
    field :is_admin, :boolean, default: false
    belongs_to :user, User
  end

  def changeset(%UserRole{} = user_role, attrs) do
    user_role
    |> cast(attrs, [:is_admin, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:is_admin])
  end
```

They are both in the same context "Accounts", where I cast the associations.

```
      #accounts.ex      
      def create_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
        %User{}
        |> User.changeset(attrs)
        |> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:user_role, required: true)
        |> Repo.insert()
      end
```

Here is the UserController's new and create:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Accounts.change_user(%User{})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    case Accounts.create_user(user_params) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :show, user))
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

I have a nested form for the User and the UserRole. If I enter all data, everything works as expected. Now, I want to hide the input for UserRole, because I don't want a user to set himself as "is_admin" (but if you are an admin, you should be able to create other admin accounts). So, there's no input for the UserRole anymore if you are a non-admin user. My expectations were that

1. the default values from the UserRole schema will be inserted, if there is no input or
2. the validation in UserRole's changeset will say that there is no input, but it is required.

What happened is: The user was created, but the associated user_role is "nil". I don't get why this happens. Can anybody explain this to me?

My solution was: Instead of giving the user a checkbox for the boolean :is_admin, I send a hidden input, setting it to false, but it seems not be the good way.

Comment: Addition: There is not even a :user_role key inserted in user_params in the UserController's create action. I deleted the hidden input in the form and now I am checking the user_params for the :user_role key. If none is there I create a new %UserRole{is_admin: false} changeset and insert it with put_assoc. This works, but nevertheless I don't get, why this is necessary, or rather why the :user_role is not inserted with the default value "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use

`Map.put_new(map, key, value)` in this case

before

`case Accounts.create_user(user_params) do`

use `params = Map.put_new(user_params, :user_role, "anything")`

what this will do is, if it finds the `:user_role` in map, it will use same, if it doesn't find anything, it will use the value you specified.

it needs the value for `user_role` because there is an association related to it. Though i feel it should be `has_many` association, but your code shows its `has_one`, so for every `user` entry there should be `user_role` associated to it.

If `has_many` is to be used, `belongs_to` should be in `user` schema, and `has_many` in `user_role` schema

Comment: Thanks, @Zubair That worked like a charm :) I think I misunderstood what the default value in the schema is for. I am aware, that the relation should be has_many. I just wanted to solve this problem first but thanks for mentioning anyway.